# Which datatype for storing HTML in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store HTML in a database, but the PhpMyAdmin on my internship's pc is not up-to-date, so there is no `nvarchar(MAX)`. What other datatype can I use, and what length would be recommended?

Comment: text ? but storing HTML is not good idea.

Comment: use filepath, instead of storing html in db

Comment: It's part of the script I have to make, that it has to insert the html itself